# Re-code and spread data in columns, based on values in another column

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a table that looks like this:

```
Year   Tax1    Tax2    Tax3    Tax4
2004     12     123     145     104
2004    145      99      90      56
2005    212     300     240     123
```

etc...

The Tax# columns give info about the tax paid in years subsequent to the value in the Year column.  I would like to re-arrange the table, and rename the columns, so it looked like this:

```
Year   Tax2004    Tax2005    Tax2006    Tax2007    Tax2008
2004        12        123        145        104         NA
2004       145         99         90         56         NA 
2005        NA        212        300        240        123
```

I was thinking of splitting the table into separate tables, based on the year column, then renaming the Tax# columns, and joining back together.  But its a bit convoluted, and I was wondering if there was a simpler way to do this?

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Even the resulting data frame looks very difficult to work with. There are better ways to manage these data IMO. What does a row represent?

Comment: Sometimes we need data in unusual formats - in this case I need to compare this data to another data frame from an alternative source. The comparison data frame is in the format that I specify - having them identical will make comparisons much simpler. Rows represent individuals.

Comment: Alternatively you could reshape the dataframe you get from the other source to perform the comparison

Comment: Yes, I could. However, I am interested in the differences for particular years - this seems much easier when data is grouped into columns representing years, compared to the format of the first table where the columns can contain values from multiple years.

Comment: I think the latter would be easier - join the two dataframes, subtract the amount column, now you have a list of differences for each year.

Comment: No, you'd have a list of differences relative to the value in the year column. It would not be straightforward to then get summary statistics for each year. Doing it as I described allows you to easily get summary statistics for the differences in each year, as they would all be in the same column. You just seem to have decided "there are better ways to manage these data" when you don't know much about it. Thankfully the answers below work great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df <- read.table(text = "
Year   Tax1    Tax2    Tax3    Tax4
2004     12     123     145     104
2004    145      99      90      56
2005    212     300     240     123
", header = TRUE)


df %>% 
  mutate(id = row_number()) %>% 
  gather(rel_year, amount, contains("Tax")) %>% 
  mutate(rel_year = as.integer(gsub("Tax", "", rel_year)),
         pay_year = Year + rel_year - 1,
         pay_year = paste0("Tax", pay_year)) %>% 
  select(-rel_year) %>% 
  spread(pay_year, amount)
```

Result:

```
  Year id Tax2004 Tax2005 Tax2006 Tax2007 Tax2008
1 2004  1      12     123     145     104      NA
2 2004  2     145      99      90      56      NA
3 2005  3      NA     212     300     240     123
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 dat1%>%
   gather(key,value,-Year)%>%
   group_by(key)%>%
   mutate(col=1:n())%>%
   ungroup()%>%
   mutate(key=paste0("Tax",2004:2008)[(Year==2005)+
         as.numeric(sub("\\D+","",key))])%>%
   spread(key,value)

# A tibble: 3 x 7
   Year   col Tax2004 Tax2005 Tax2006 Tax2007 Tax2008
  <int> <int>   <int>   <int>   <int>   <int>   <int>
1  2004     1      12     123     145     104      NA
2  2004     2     145      99      90      56      NA
3  2005     3      NA     212     300     240     123
>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
library(readr)
dcast(melt(setDT(df, keep.rownames = TRUE), id.var = c("rn", "Year"))[,
  newYear := paste0("Tax", Year + parse_number(variable) - 1)], 
     rn + Year~ newYear, value.var = 'value')[, rn := NULL][]
#    Year Tax2004 Tax2005 Tax2006 Tax2007 Tax2008
#1: 2004      12     123     145     104      NA
#2: 2004     145      99      90      56      NA
#3: 2005      NA     212     300     240     123
```